# NTFS partition mounting error

Tags: xubuntu

Earlier I installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode, back then opening any of my Windows drives were not a problem but now when i try to open any Drive with NTFS format, it shows an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2hks.png).

I am new to Linux and a lot of time I face problem like it shows that my laptop is connected to my WiFi but internet doesn't works or a lot of time my USB ports like my wireless mouse doesn't work. Any proper fix for all these issues??

Comment: Your answer to NTFS mounting has been answered. For other issues please post a question with proper screenshots and hints so that we could help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Windows.

Goto start menu:

1. Type: `cmd`.
2. Right-click on it and click on `Run as Administrator`.

Then, type the following command and reboot:

```
powercfg.exe -h off
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks man the solution helped. But there is one more problem, the USB problem was solved after i did latest update but this WiFi problem exists and its a pain, actually what happens is my laptop gets connected to the WiFi, it shows that it is connected but internet doesn't work, i checked your solution about an hour ago, solved the error, but as i was on Ubuntu i wasn't able to reply, trying to connect it for 1 hr finally i switched to windows and now i am replying. Solution to this problem would be a great great relief.

Comment: @PrateekCoder - Can you please ask a new question and share the link to that question here, so that I can help? Thank you!

Comment: there u go: http://askubuntu.com/questions/713089/internetwifi-connectivity-issue-in-ubuntu and if there is any info requirement please ask me to do so the only thing is i will have to take the screenshot in ubuntu and then take it in my usb log in again in windows and then post u here may take a while but i will try to provide u with required info asap.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably turning off Windows by hibernating it. When you do this, you are essentially pausing the system and saving all of that information into a file `hiberfil.sys`.

Making changes to your Windows NTFS partition - and to the file `hiberfil.sys` - while it is hibernated could be dangerous. Because of this, Ubuntu will not mount the partition in read-write mode if it sees a hibernation flag, and that's why Nautilus pops up that error.